# Can I run aws-xray on the same ECS container?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-xray

I don't want to have to deploy a whole other ECS service just to enable X-Ray. I'm hoping I can run X-Ray on the same docker container as my app, I would have thought that was the preferred way of running it. I know there might be some data loss if my container dies. But I don't much care about that, I'm trying to stop this proliferation of extra services which serve only extra analytical/logging functions, I already have a logstash container I'm not happy about, my feeling is that apps themselves should be able to do this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the proper way to do this is using [supervisord](https://riptutorial.com/docker/example/14132/dockerfile-plus-supervisord-conf), see link for an example of that, but I ended up just making a very simple script:

```
# start.sh
/usr/bin/xray &
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run
```

And then having a Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jdk11-openjdk

RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN curl -o daemon.zip https://s3.dualstack.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aws-xray-assets.us-east-2/xray-daemon/aws-xray-daemon-linux-3.x.zip
RUN unzip daemon.zip && cp xray /usr/bin/xray

# COPY APPLICATION
# TODO

COPY start.sh /usr/bin/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/usr/bin/start.sh"]
```

I think I will look at using `supervisord` next time.

Comment: Don't forget to give your container a role to access X-Ray.

Answer (score 0):

While we have the Dockerhub image of the X-Ray Daemon, you can absolutely run the daemon in the same docker container as your application - that shouldn't be an issue.

Here's the typical setup with the daemon dockerfile and task definition instructions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-ecs.html

I imagine you can simply omit the task definition attributes around the daemon, since it would be running locally beside your application - those wouldn't be used at all.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, I need an actual Dockerfile example, that documentation is easy to come by, I have a tomcat app.