# Integrating X-Ray with existed ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I already have a ECS Cluster deployed in multiple EC2. Now I want to integrate them with X-Ray for troubleshooting some issues.

Is there a way to do this without re-deploy cluster?

On another side, I using the start.sh and the Dockerfile in [Can I run aws-xray on the same ECS container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701384/can-i-run-aws-xray-on-the-same-ecs-container) to generate a tomcat container with xray inside but the XRay console is still empty after open port 2000 TCP and UDP in role, open all in NACL. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Getting X-Ray to work with your application has two parts: (1) Instrumenting your application with an [AWS X-Ray SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java.html). Doing this will generate trace data for your application. (2) Running the [daemon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon.html) process so that the SDK can send the trace data to the X-Ray service to be displayed in the console. You have done only the 2nd part. Once you instrument your application, you'd need to redeploy it in the cluster.